# Запуск объекта на постоянную работу?

Tags: java, javafx

Подскажите, как можно реализовать.
Есть переключатель. Возвращает только истина и ложь. Нужно, что бы, когда от него приходит  истина запускался сервер, и продолжал работать не обращая внимания на переключатель?

```
setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
          switchedOn.set(!switchedOn.get());
          int pong ;

          if (switchedOn.get()) {

             System.out.println(switchedOn.get());

             Service<Void> service = new Service<Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Task<Void> createTask() {
                    return new Task<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Void call() throws Exception {

                         Запускаем сервер.

                          return null;
                        }
                    };
                }
             };
             service.start();               
          }

});
```

Comment: ничего непонятно. какой серевер? какой переключатель?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor немного подправил

Comment: Можно удалять листенер после запуска

Comment: Может проще setEnabled(false) сделать для элемента выключателя?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вводите флаг, отвечающий за работу объекта:

```
НаКаждыйКликИлиСобытие {
    если (Переключатель == true) и (УжеРаботает == false) {
        НачатьРаботу;
        УжеРаботает = true;
    }
}
```

Не забудьте `УжеРаботает` сделать глобальной переменной, либо передавать её в `НаКаждыйКликИлиСобытие` в качестве параметра.

Answer (score 1):

Для проверки состояния можно воспользоваться методом `Service.isRunning()`.

В контроллере:

```
private Service<Void> service;

public void runServer(ActionEvent event) {

    if (toggleButton.isSelected()) {

        if (service == null || !service.isRunning()) {
            service = new Service<Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Task<Void> createTask() {
                    return new Task<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Void call() throws Exception {

                            //"Запускаем" сервер:
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                            toggleButton.setPrefWidth(toggleButton.getWidth() + 100);

                            return null;
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
            service.start();
        }
    }
}
```

FXML:

```
<ToggleButton fx:id="toggleButton" text="Разрешить запуск сервера" />
<Button onAction="#runServer" text="Пуск" />
```